# Get all logging output with mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, mocking

I want to get all logging output with mock. I searched, but
only found ways to mock explicitly logging.info or logging.warn.

I need all output, whatever logging level was set.

```
def test_foo():

   def my_log(...):
      logs.append(...)

   with mock.patch('logging.???', my_log):
        ...
```

In our libraries we use this:

```
import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

def foo():
    logger.info(...)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## stdlib

Since Python 3.4 the batteries' `unittest` has [`assertLogs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs). When used without `logger` and `level` arguments, it catches all logging (suppresses existing handlers). You can later access recorded entries from the context manager's `records` attribute. Text output strings are stored in `output` list.

```
import logging
import unittest


class TestLogging(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        with self.assertLogs() as ctx:
            logging.getLogger('foo').info('message from foo')
            logging.getLogger('bar').info('message from bar')
        print(ctx.records)
```

## Tornado

For Python 2 I usually take Tornado's [`ExpectLog`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.ExpectLog). It's self-contained and works for normal Python code. It's actually more elegant solution then stdlib's, because instead of several class, `ExpectLog` is just a normal [`logging.Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) (a class, [source](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/6682d58bf2/tornado/testing.py#L555)). But it lacks a couple of features, including access to recorded entries, so usually I also extend it a bit, like:

```
class ExpectLog(logging.Filter):

    def __init__(self, logger, regex, required=True, level=None):
        if isinstance(logger, basestring):
            logger = logging.getLogger(logger)
        self.logger = logger
        self.orig_level = self.logger.level
        self.level = level
        self.regex = re.compile(regex)
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter()
        self.required = required
        self.matched = []
        self.logged_stack = False

    def filter(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            self.logged_stack = True
        message = self.formatter.format(record)
        if self.regex.search(message):
            self.matched.append(record)
            return False
        return True

    def __enter__(self):
        self.logger.addFilter(self)
        if self.level:
            self.logger.setLevel(self.level)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, tb):
        self.logger.removeFilter(self)
        if self.level:
            self.logger.setLevel(self.orig_level)
        if not typ and self.required and not self.matched:
            raise Exception("did not get expected log message")
```

Then you can have something like:

```
class TestLogging(unittest.TestCase):

    def testTornadoself):
        logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)

        with ExpectLog('foo', '.*', required = False) as ctxFoo:
            with ExpectLog('bar', '.*', required = False) as ctxBar:
                logging.getLogger('foo').info('message from foo')
                logging.getLogger('bar').info('message from bar')
        print(ctxFoo.matched)
        print(ctxBar.matched)
```

However, note that for the filter approach current logging level is important (can be overridden with `level` argument), and also you need a filter per logger of interest. You can follow the approach and make something that fits your case better.

## Update

Alternatively there's [unittest2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) backport for Python 2 which has `assertLogs`.

Comment: I like the stdlib solution the most. Up to now I am still fixed on Python 2.7 but sooner or later we will be there. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with a reference to unittest2 backport, so you use the same approach throughout.

Comment: nice, a backport. Yes, we still use Python2.7.  I ask myself why there are so many choices in the Python world. Sometimes this is great, sometimes confusing :-) In this case: unittest2 vs pytest.

Comment: is it safe to assume that the order of `log.records` will be in the same order as the logs are recorded? it's not sorted by level for instance?

Comment: I think it's safe to assume so. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/26f18b85/Lib/unittest/_log.py#L56) `handlers` of the target logger are temporarily changed to an instance of `_CapturingHandler`, where its [`emit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/26f18b85/Lib/unittest/_log.py#L22) just appends to the two list, original logging records to one and their formatted representation to the other.

Answer (score 19):

### `pytest`

If you are writing your tests using `pytest`, take a look at a neat fixture named `caplog` that will capture log records for you. It captures all the emitted log records which you can then access via `caplog.records` list. Each element is an instance of `logging.LogRecord`, so you can easily access any of the [`LogRecord`s attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). Example:

```python
# spam.py

import logging
logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

def foo():
    logger.info('bar')


# tests.py

import logging
from spam import foo

def test_foo(caplog):
    foo()
    assert len(caplog.records) == 1
    record = next(iter(caplog.records))
    assert record.message == 'bar'
    assert record.levelno == logging.INFO
    assert record.module == 'spam'
    # etc
```

#### Install

The fixture was first introduced in a `pytest` plugin named `pytest-capturelog` which is now abandoned. Luckily, it got a decent fork named `pytest-catchlog`, [which has been merged into `pytest==3.3.0`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#pytest-3-3-0-2017-11-23) recently. So, if you use a recent version of `pytest`, you are already good to go; for older versions of `pytest`, [install `pytest-catchlog` from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog/).

#### Docs

At the moment, `pytest` doesn't provide any docs for the `caplog` fixture (or at least I couldn't find any), so you can refer to `pytest-catchlog`'s [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-catchlog/).

### Plain `unittest`

If `pytest` is not an option, I wouldn't patch `logging` at all - you can simply add a custom handler instead that will record all the incoming logs. A small example:

```
# utils.py

import logging


class RecordsCollector(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.records = []

    def emit(self, record):
        self.records.append(record)


# tests.py

import logging
import unittest
from utils import RecordsCollector
from spam import foo


class SpamTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.collector = RecordsCollector()
        logging.getLogger('spam').addHandler(self.collector)

    def tearDown(self):
        logging.getLogger('spam').removeHandler(self.collector)

    def test_foo(self):
        foo()
        # same checks as in the example above
        self.assertEqual(len(self.collector.records), 1)
        record = next(iter(self.collector.records))
        self.assertEqual(record.message, 'bar')
        self.assertEqual(record.levelno, logging.INFO)
        self.assertEqual(record.module, 'spam')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You can then extend the custom handler and implement any logic you need, like collecting the records in a `dict` that maps log levels to lists of records, or add a `contextmanager` implementation, so you can start and stop capturing records inside the test:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def record_logs():
    collector = RecordsCollector()
    logging.getLogger('spam').addHandler(collector)
    yield collector
    logging.getLogger('spam').removeHandler(collector)


def test_foo(self):
    with utils.record_logs() as collector:
        foo()
        self.assertEqual(len(collector.records), 1)
```

Comment: Good news! Up to now I use an older version, but this is reason to upgrade. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! I also added a solution proposal for the `unittest`-tests, for the sake of completeness. Although the proposal mostly mimics the `caplog` fixture implementation...

Comment: Documentation for the pytest-`caplog`-fixture can be found here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html
And thanks for the `unittest` - example. That worked for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

The module testfixtures has a class to handle this:

```
>>> import logging
>>> from testfixtures import LogCapture
>>> with LogCapture() as l:
...     logger = logging.getLogger()
...     logger.info('a message')
...     logger.error('an error')

>>> l.check(
...     ('root', 'INFO', 'a message'),
...     ('root', 'ERROR', 'another error'),
...     )
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
AssertionError: sequence not as expected:

same:
(('root', 'INFO', 'a message'),)

expected:
(('root', 'ERROR', 'another error'),)

actual:
(('root', 'ERROR', 'an error'),)
```

Source: http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
def test_foo(self):

    logs=[]

    def my_log(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logs.append((args, kwargs))

    with mock.patch('logging.Logger._log', my_log):
        ...
```

Comment: I think this solution is too complicated.